# Почему число ноль не добавляется в массив при помощи?

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте.почему когда я использую filter число 0 не добавляется в массив?

```js
function filter_list(l) {
  let arr = l.filter(function(i){
    if(typeof i === "number"){
     return i;
    }
   });
  return arr;
}

console.log(filter_list([1,'a','b',0,15]) == [1,0,15])
```